# Is it possible to use a non-AAD IdP with Azure Databricks?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, idp

Is it possible to use an alternative (Non-AAD) Identity Provider (IdP) with Azure Databricks? Or is AAD the only option?

I ask because in the Databricks [native documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/users-groups/scim/index.html#account-level-and-workspace-level-scim-provisioning), the IdP shows OneLogin, Okta, etc.

But in the *Azure* Databricks [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/users-groups/scim/#--account-level-and-workspace-level-scim-provisioning), the IdP shows Azure Active Directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Databricks could be used only with AAD, you can't setup **direct** SSO integration with other IdP (same for other Azure services). The "native" documentation that you're referring is applicable only for AWS.

But it's possible to setup federation between 3rd party IdPs and AAD ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation)), so users could be authenticated by other IdP, and then Azure Databricks will get user's identity from AAD.